# download file by aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have few files in S3, need to download the same from an Angular download button as in zip format.
how to zip files from S3 in lambda and how to return the zip file as an attachment from lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Much like a regular Python webservice route (like Flask or Django). You would use the `boto` package to download the files, `zipfile` to produce the .zip file in memory or in temporary storage, and send its bytes in the response with the appropriate `Content-disposition` header.

This is assuming you need to join multiple S3 files into a zip, dynamically, in the request. If the file you need to send is already in S3 and you need it as-is, you just need to return an HTTP response redirecting to an [S3 presigned URL](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html).

Comment: Maybe you can post a separate question with full code?

Answer (score 0):

Updated the same with s3predesigned url.